# Django site throws 502 Error on large Postgres queries

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, nginx

when I make postgres queries using django's queryset, it loads the data fine so long as the query isn't returning more than a few dozen results.  However, on larger queries, django spits out a 502 bad gateway error.  Any idea as to why this might be, and how I could fix it?  I've tried a lot of the db optimization stuff listed in the documentation, and have even clustered the db based on the specific filtering parameter, all to no avail.  Has anyone else had a similar issue?  What did you do?

Error log:

```
2015/08/01 20:00:13 [error] 20509#0: *725 upstream prematurely closed connection
while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.54.224.162,
server: 45.55.165.48, request: "POST /candidates/query/ HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "unix:/webapps/cruit/cruit/run/gunicorn.sock:/candidates/query/…;,
host: "45.55.165.48", referrer: "45.55.165.48/"
```

Comment: What's in the Django / nginx error logs? That should have details.

Comment: it says this:
2015/08/01 20:00:13 [error] 20509#0: *725 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.54.224.162, server: 45.55.165.48, request: "POST /candidates/query/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/webapps/cruit/cruit/run/gunicorn.sock:/candidates/query/", host: "45.55.165.48", referrer: "http://45.55.165.48/"

Comment: Update your nginx config to increase the proxy timeouts

Comment: I can't find the nginx settings?  What does the path look like?

Answer (score 0):

Django likely runs out of memory when loading query results, it is known to do that when using ORM objects. You should check your memory usage during query execution and immediately after the `502` - you would see a spike and a sharp drop if you were ineed running out of memory.

If this is the case, you can try loading less objects, implement paging or load just object values using `my_queryset.values('value1', 'value2', ...)` instead of creating ORM objects for each result row.

Comment: Hm. it looks like memory is the issue here.  Unfortunately, due to the nature of the query, I cannot implement pagination.  I have the results of the query display as a table that is sortable by different fields, which doesn't lend itself to pages.  Does using queryset.values still allow me to access the different model fields?

Comment: Hm.  Still working on this and have yet to figure it out.  when I click on the actual error "http://ip.address/query/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" in chrome's console, it brings up more details.  There, it says

HTTP 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

{

    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

}

I know that "GET" is allowed, since it retrieves the appropriate data on smaller queries, but this error message makes it sound like there's something structurally wrong with my code.  Any idea as to why it shows up as a 405 error when I click 'details'?

Comment: @TerryMarting i get the same error, did you get any luck finding the cause ?